# Method Not Allowed HTTP Exception in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have a form with two text fields and two buttons (edit and delete), when I press edit button, it works fine but when I press delete button, it gives the 'MethodNotAllowedHttp' exception. My code is as follows:

```
<form action="/laboratory/doctors/update" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="name" value="{{ $doctor->name }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="percentage">Percentage:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="percentage" value="{{ $doctor->percentage }}">
    </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
    <a href="/laboratory/doctors/{{ $doctor->id }}/delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
</form>
```

My Routes are as follows:

```
Route::post('/doctors/update', 'DoctorsController@update');
Route::delete('/doctors/{doctor}/delete', 'DoctorsController@destroy');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you have form which action is `action="/laboratory/doctors/update" method="POST"` and in same form you have delete method, so you got the errors!

Answer (score 1):

You have created route of http verbs as `delete` type and trying to get of type `get`. So you can change it as `get` instead `delete`

```
 Route::get('/laboratory/doctors/{doctor}/delete', 'DoctorsController@destroy');
```

Also there is other way to make http verb as `DELETE` but using

1. Another `form` tag outside of current `form` tag.
2. Or use ajax to make it `delete` type

Comment: May be OP take `/laboratory` as a prefix in route!

Comment: Let you see if this helps to OP!

Answer (score 0):

Href on an anchor html element will result in a GET call but your route expect a Delete call. You have some ways to make sure you will result in a delete call.

One of the most common ways is to use a form instead to post data to your server.

**DELETE**

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '/laboratory/doctors/{{ $doctor->id }}/delete', 'method' => 'DELETE']) }}
{{ Form::button('delete', ['type' => 'submit', 
                           'class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

For best practise I recommend to use `{{ Form::open(...) }}` `{{ Form::close() }}` only once and refactor your controller code so it can read the value from the buttons and translate that in the corresponding `{doctor}` of the delete post so you dont have multiple html forms in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(isset($doctor))
<form action="/laboratory/doctors/{{$doctor->id}}/delete" method="POST">
@else
<form action="/laboratory/doctors/update" method="POST">
@endif
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @if(isset($doctor))
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    @endif
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="name" value="{{ $doctor->name }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="percentage">Percentage:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="percentage" value="{{ $doctor->percentage }}">
    </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
    <a href="/laboratory/doctors/{{ $doctor->id }}/delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
</form>
```

The problem is in your action.. when you click delete button, the button run the destroy function, but the form run the update function. So, you have to separate the form action, or you can delete it by using ajax